# Aligning div centrally inside other div and an image centrally both vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to achieve the following: I have a central div (wrapper) exactly in the center of my page, both vertically and horizontally. Inside that div I want to have another 2 divs, one of which will contain a logo and the other some text. The logo image also has to be aligned vertically and horizontally to the center of its div. Currently this is what I have:

[image]

Here's the jsfiddle with my HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/7cQhG/

How can I center the logo div (only centered horizontally, and have a 10px margin-top) and have the logo image centered inside that div, both horizontally and vertically, just as it is now)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you have to have the logo as an img?

I've taken the starting point you gave, and put together a jsFiddle fork : http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/HDmkZ/

I've taken out the img tag, and used it as a background image. "center center" should theoretically center it within its container, and as it's a transparent png, your background color still shows up as you wanted.

Let me know if this works for you, or if you have any other questions.

As a sidebar, you really don't need (and you really shouldn't) to specify your tags in your CSS. The only place that's really appropriate is if you're assigning defaults to a specific tag... otherwise, rules of specificity are already going to take over when you're using those IDs you've got in there.

Note that I wasn't clear what you wanted to do with the text below the logo, so I didn't do any styling, there.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm really OK with the logo image being the BG for the div at the moment, if there's no other way to center it. I didn't deal with the text yet, I'll try to style it myself now. And thank you for the tags explanation! Appreciate it!

Comment: Note that the only caveat to this method is that you'll find IE6 does not like your PNG, not without some help from some PNG shim code. Hopefully, that's not a concern you have, but if so, look at the following link for possible help: http://htmlandcssbook.com/extras/transparent-pngs-in-ie6/